# Output all cells in a named range in Excel?

Tags: excel-2007, worksheet-function, named-ranges

I have a named range in Excel (called `JourneyReference`) that contains data to do with common journeys employees make (travel time, distance, etc). I would like to output all of the cells from this named range on several sheets.

The reason I am looking at doing it this way is because the named range will be updated regularly, and thus I'd like the changes in it to propagate through to all the sheets.

Is this possible in Excel 2007? Or, if there is perhaps a better way of doing this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: A named range may not be the best answer, hence my last paragraph. If you post an answer that will achieve the same results using a different method I will gladly accept it. Further more, if it is not a SO question then the tag `worksheet-function` would not be here.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you need to give a lot more information to figure out what you need to know.